# tomcatが起動しない

Tags: tomcat

CentOS7にtomcatをインストールするため、以下のようにコマンドを実行しました。

```
yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64
yum install -y tomcat
wget -p /usr/share/tomcat/webapps/ https://github.com/gitbucket/gitbucket/releases/download/4.26.0/gitbucket.war
```

tomcatを起動させようとするとエラーがでましたが、原因がわかりません。

```
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl start tomcat
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl status tomcat
● tomcat.service - Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/tomcat.service; disabled; vendor 
preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since 火 2018-07-10 17:54:19 JST; 1s 
ago
Process: 26576 ExecStart=/usr/libexec/tomcat/server start (code=exited, 
status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 26576 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

7月 10 17:54:19 localhost.localdomain server[26576]: options used: - 
Dcatalina.base=/usr/share/tomcat -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat - 
Djava.en...gManager
7月 10 17:54:19 localhost.localdomain server[26576]: arguments used: start
7月 10 17:54:19 localhost.localdomain server[26576]: Exception in thread 
"main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/juli/logging/LogFactory
7月 10 17:54:19 localhost.localdomain server[26576]: at 
org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.<clinit>(Bootstrap.java:49)
7月 10 17:54:19 localhost.localdomain server[26576]: Caused by: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory
7月 10 17:54:19 localhost.localdomain server[26576]: at 
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
7月 10 17:54:19 localhost.localdomain server[26576]: at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
7月 10 17:54:19 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: tomcat.service: main 
process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
7月 10 17:54:19 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit tomcat.service 
entered failed state.
7月 10 17:54:19 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: tomcat.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Comment: 手元の環境(Cnetos7.3)で試したけど再現しませんでした。Tomcatの設定はなにかされてますか？ /etc/sysconfig/tomcat の内容を掲載できますか？ あと本筋とずれてますが wget のオプションは間違ってる気がしますが Typoでしょうか。

Comment: 追伸です。/etc/tomcat/tomcat.conf も読み込まれるようなので 掲載をお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcatの設定ファイルや起動スクリプトを変更していることが原因で、`CLASSPATH`に`tomcat-juli.jar`が指定されていないのではないかと思います。

通常、`tomcat-juli.jar`（や`bootstrap.jar`）は`${CATALINA_HOME}/lib/`ではなく`${CATALINA_HOME}/bin/`にあり、起動スクリプトの中で`CLASSPATH`に設定されます。

Answer (score 1):

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory
の行にある通り、org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactoryというクラスが見つからないと言っています。

org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactoryについて調べて、不足しているライブラリをインストールしてみてください。

Comment: @user28019 tomcat-juli.jar をクラスパスに通す必要があるみたいです。 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955442/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-juli-logging-logfactory